# Accessing parent select value in pop-window or save into a temp table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of select as below.

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="addpp.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
        <table width="100%">
                       <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select name="leftProcess" size="5">
                                            <option value="1">Process 1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Process 2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Process 3</option>
                                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <button onclick="moveRight('leftProcess','rightProcess')">>></button><br/>
                           <button onclick="moveLeft('rightProcess','leftProcess')"><<</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rightProcess" size="5">

                            </select>
                        </td>
                       </tr>


                       <tr>
                        Sub process for Process 1
                        <td>
                            <select name="leftSubProcess1" size="5">
                                            <option value="1">Sub 1_1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Sub 1_2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Sub 1_3</option>
                                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <button onclick="moveRight('leftSubProcess1','rightSubProcess1')">>></button><br/>
                           <button onclick="moveLeft('rightSubProcess1','leftSubProcess1')"><<</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rightSubProcess1" size="5">

                            </select>
                        </td>
                       </tr>


                       <tr>
                        Sub process for Process 2
                        <td>
                            <select name="leftSubProcess2" size="5">
                                            <option value="1">Sub 2_1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Sub 2_2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Sub 2_3</option>
                                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <button onclick="moveRight('leftSubProcess2','rightSubProcess2')">>></button><br/>
                           <button onclick="moveLeft('rightSubProcess2','leftSubProcess2')"><<</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rightSubProcess2" size="5">

                            </select>
                        </td>
                       </tr>


                       <tr>
                        Sub process for Process 3
                        <td>
                            <select name="leftSubProcess3" size="5">
                                            <option value="1">Sub 3_1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Sub 3_2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Sub 3_3</option>
                                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <button onclick="moveRight('leftSubProcess3','rightSubProcess3')">>></button><br/>
                           <button onclick="moveLeft('rightSubProcess3','leftSubProcess3')"><<</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rightSubProcess3" size="5">

                            </select>
                        </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                       <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add"  style="width:80px; height:25px;"></input>
            <input type="button" name="Preview" onclick="javascript:openChildWindow();" value="Preview"  style="width:80px; height:25px;"/>
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel"  style="width:80px; height:25px;"/>
        </td>
</tr>
                  </table>
    </form>
```

The first select will be all the process so user can choose and push them to the right select box. Accordingly the 3 below select are for sub process for the all the process above. User can also pick and choose which one they would desire.Once I cick the preview button I would the user to view their selection in this format. For e.g. use pickProcess 3 followed by Process 2 and Process 1. So then below must first show all the sub_proces3 then sub_process2 and sub_process1. What is best was to select and show these sort of data must I like save into a temp table? The idea is to give them a preview what they have select before the final submission into database.

Comment: You can reference parent elements from the `window.opener` chain.  example:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Comment: I have read about it but how to read all the select values I got no idea and how to rearrange them according to my selected process sequence. If I put in db I know how to retrieve and show accordingly

Comment: No need to use a database.  Store the button left and right movements in a data-var on an element.  You can read/write directly to inputs with html5 data  So, you can store a number that represents its position.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: Any sample codest on this maybe on sample how to read one of the select say the <select name="rightProcess" size="5"> in my pop-up ?

Comment: `window.opener.document.form.field.value` should get it (for text boxes).  selects you should use the standard selectedIndex style read